# Is it possible to use serial port in WinCE 5.0 emulator?

Tags: windows-ce, serial-port, emulation

Is it possible to use PC's serial port (com1) for WinCE 5.0 emulator? How to do that?

FYI, I am working on a program which will communicate with another device using serial port. I need to use winCE emulator to test the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Open the emulator, then use the menu to go to File -> Configure.  Switch to the "Peripherals" tab and set the serial port mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much ctacke. Just to mention that I was trying in wince 5.0 emulator so far where there is no option to add serial port. Now I found out I would have to run from visual studio.